# Search lighttpd access log

Tags: log-files, lighttpd, grep, sed

The access-log on my `lighttpd` server is kind of huge, apx 5GB.

Now I need to extract all data from a given date, 12th of February, from the log file and if possible save to new file. Is it possible to search the file somehow?

I have tried below `sed` with no success:

```
sed -n '/Feb 12 00:00:54/ , /Feb 13 00:50:28/p' /var/log/myserver--access_log
```

Maybe some `grep` I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just

```
grep "Feb 12" /var/log/myserver--access_log
```

should work. You can pipe it directly into a different file by adding

```
> /path/to/the/file.txt
```

in the back of the line.